# Receive ArrayList from Custom Adapter

Tags: android, arraylist

Ive got a Array List in my CustomAdapter filled with the id of my checked element.

```
 elementChecker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (elementChecker.isChecked()) {
                checkedElements.add(id);
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedElements.size() ; i++){
                    checkedElements.remove(id);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But how do I get access to this list from my Fragment?Thanks for your help.

EDIT: This is my getter But I cant call it from my Fragment.

```
    public List<String> getSelectedElements(){
    return checkedElements;
}
```

The Adapter is set in my DataListFragment:

```
    final ListAdapter dataListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, dataListArray);
        final ListView dataListListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_datalist);

        dataListListView.setAdapter(dataListAdapter);
```

EDIT2: Added The Fragment Code

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

    DbHelper mydb;
    Spinner locationpicker;

    LinearLayout qrStickerLayout;
    ImageView qrCodeSticker;
    TextView labelSticker;
    TextView serialSticker;


    private EditText roomnr;

    public boolean roomNrOk = false;
    public boolean locationOk = false;
    public boolean listViewOk = false;

    String actualLocation;
    String dataList = "";
    String selectedFromList;
    String[] selectedElementArray;




    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

        getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.listView));

        registerForContextMenu(view);

        final Context context = getContext();
        mydb = new DbHelper(context);
        locationpicker = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_locations);
        roomnr = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_roomNr);

        qrCodeSticker = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_qrcode);
        labelSticker = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_QrSticker_label);
        serialSticker = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_QrSticker_serial);
        qrStickerLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_QrCode);


        Drawable drawableForFabSave = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_save);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabsave.setImageDrawable(drawableForFabSave);

        Drawable drawableForFabAdd = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabmain.setImageDrawable(drawableForFabAdd);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabmain.animate().translationY(0);
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabmain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).scanQRCode();
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).loadListViewFragment();
            }
        });

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabdelete.animate().translationY(0);

        final String locationNamesFromTableArray = mydb.getLocationNames();

        if(!locationNamesFromTableArray.isEmpty()){
            String[] roomNumbersFromTableArrayFinal = locationNamesFromTableArray.split("\t");
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_locations;
            adapter_locations = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, roomNumbersFromTableArrayFinal);
            locationpicker.setAdapter(adapter_locations);

            setFabdeleteVisible(listViewOk);
        }

        locationpicker.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                actualLocation = locationpicker.getSelectedItem().toString();
                locationOk = true;
                setFabsVisible(roomNrOk, true, listViewOk);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        roomnr.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{3}$");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

                roomNrOk = m.find();
                setFabsVisible(roomNrOk, locationOk, listViewOk);
            }
        });

        dataList = mydb.getElementsWithoutRoom();


        if (!dataList.isEmpty()) {
            final String[] dataListArray = dataList.split("\n");

            final ListAdapter dataListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, dataListArray);
            final ListView dataListListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_datalist);

            dataListListView.setAdapter(dataListAdapter);

            dataListListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    selectedFromList = (dataListListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                    selectedElementArray = selectedFromList.split("\t");
                    dataListListView.showContextMenu();
                }

            });

            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabdelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mydb.deleteAllWithoutRoom();
                    listViewOk = false;
                    dataListListView.setAdapter(dataListAdapter);

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, getResources().getString(R.string.toast_deleted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                    reloadListViewFragment();
                }
            });

        }else{
            TextView emptyElement = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emptyElement);
            emptyElement.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (roomNrOk && locationOk && !dataList.isEmpty()) {
                    String successfullSaved = getResources().getString(R.string.successfully)+ actualLocation + "-" + roomnr.getText().toString() + getResources().getString(R.string.saved);

                    mydb.setRoomNr(roomnr.getText().toString());
                    mydb.setRoomId(roomnr.getText().toString());

                    mydb.setLocationId(actualLocation);

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), successfullSaved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                    reloadListViewFragment();
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.error_listView), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).fabexport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile() + getResources().getString(R.string.sdcard_path));
                    if (!myDir.exists()) {
                        myDir.mkdir();
                    }
                    String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.roomname) + actualLocation + getResources().getString(R.string.underline) + roomnr.getText().toString() + getResources().getString(R.string.roomname_ending);
                    File file = new File(myDir, fileName);
                    file.createNewFile();

                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    OutputStreamWriter fos = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    fos.write(dataList);
                    fos.close();
                    fOut.close();

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), fileName + getResources().getString(R.string.saved), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    public void reloadListViewFragment(){
        Fragment fragment;
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragment = new ListViewFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can create a getter method for this.

Comment: I have one. But I am not able to call it in my Fragment.

Comment: Where you are setting the adapter?

Comment: In my DataListFragment

Comment: So, write `dataListAdapter.getSelectedElements()` in your fragment.

Comment: And there is the problem "Cannot resolve method".

Comment: Can you just post the code for fragment?

Comment: added the fragment code (a little shortened)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I got that, the issue is because the `dataListAdapter` is of type `ListAdapter` where you are initializing with `CustomListAdapter`. So, it gave you the error **Cannot resolve method**. To resolve this you can do it two ways:-

1. You can change this line

`final ListAdapter dataListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, dataListArray);`

to

`final CustomListAdapter dataListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, dataListArray);`

2. While accessing the `getSelectedElements()`, write like this

`((CustomListAdapter)dataListAdapter).getSelectedElements();`

Please check with the current answer and let me know for further.